# IndexOutOfBoundsException while accessing List

Tags: java, arraylist, io

I'm working on a project for a class, and I think I've got it mostly figured out, but it keeps giving me different Exception errors and now I'm stumped.

The instructions can be found here: http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/cse1223/currentsem/projects/CSE1223Project11.html

Here is the code I have thus far, currently giving me and IndexOutOfBounds exception in the getMaximum method.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project11a {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter an input file name: ");
        String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        System.out.print("Enter an output file name: ");
        String outFile = keyboard.nextLine();
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String name = in.nextLine();
            List<Integer> series = readNextSeries(in);
            int mean = getAverage(series);
            int median = getMedian(series);
            int max = getMaximum(series);
            int min = getMinimum(series);
            outputFile.printf("%-22s%6d%n", name, mean, median, max, min);
        }
        in.close();
        outputFile.close();

    }

    // Given a Scanner as input read in a list of integers one at a time until a
    // negative
    // value is read from the Scanner. Store these integers in an
    // ArrayList<Integer> and
    // return the ArrayList<Integer> to the calling program.
    private static List<Integer> readNextSeries(Scanner inScanner) {
        List<Integer> nextSeries = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (inScanner.hasNextInt()) {
            int currentLine = inScanner.nextInt();
            if (currentLine != -1) {
                nextSeries.add(currentLine);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return nextSeries;
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the median of the list and
    // return it to
    // the calling program.
    private static int getMedian(List<Integer> inList) {
        Collections.sort(inList);
        int middle = inList.size() / 2;
        int median = -1;
        if (inList.size() % 2 == 1) {
            median = inList.get(middle);
        } else {
            try {
                median = (inList.get(middle - 1) + inList.get(middle)) / 2;
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
        return median;
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the average of the list and
    // return it to
    // the calling program.
    private static int getAverage(List<Integer> inList) {
        int average = 0;
        if (inList.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < inList.size(); i++) {
            average += inList.get(i);
        }
        return (average / inList.size());
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the maximum of the list and
    // return it to
    // the calling program.
    private static int getMaximum(List<Integer> inList) {
        int max = inList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < inList.size(); i++) {
            if (inList.get(i) > max) {
                max = inList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    // Given a List<Integer> of integers, compute the maximum of the list and
    // return it to
    // the calling program.
    private static int getMinimum(List<Integer> inList) {
        int min = inList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < inList.size(); i++) {
            if (inList.get(i) < min) {
                min = inList.get(i);
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by reading the stack trace of the exception. It tells you what and where the problem is, what the size of the collection is, and what the incorrect index is.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed like that your list is empty.
What can triggered the exception is the statement:

```
int max = inList.get(0);
```

So your inList do not have the value in the first index,which means the inList is empty.